# Reusing HttpClient with multiple base addresses

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have dotnet core web api hosted on Azure. The Web API works as a HUB, where it has to distribute the message to different endpoints every time based on certain criteria and my `HttpClientHandler` is the same always. How do I reuse the `HttpClient` with multiple base addresses.

Comment: You don't. You make multiple of them.

Comment: See [Named HttpClients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#named-clients) or [Typed Clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients)

Comment: @Bhaskar was my answer helpful? If so please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpClient.BaseAddress` is a convenience feature that exists specifically for scenarios where you're making calls to the same base address. You're doing the opposite of that, and you're not required to set it, so don't. Just set the absolute URI for each request.